# How to use multer-s3's type definition for req.file rather than multer's

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I am migrating from JS to TS and encountering some issues along the way. I'm using the widely known *multer* package with a custom storage engine *multer-s3* to efficiently stream incoming files directly to AWS.

The custom storage engine, multer-s3, thereby provides its own definition of the "file" property which extends multer's definition. multer-s3's `index.d.ts` file looks like this (multer-s3's full type definitions can be found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/multer-s3/index.d.ts)):

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        namespace MulterS3 {
            interface File extends Multer.File {
                bucket: string;
                key: string;
                acl: string;
                contentType: string;
                contentDisposition: null;
                storageClass: string;
                serverSideEncryption: null;
                metadata: any;
                location: string;
                etag: string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm parsing incoming files though, multer uses its own definition of File rather than multer-s3's definition, which causes properties, like `location`, to be unavailable on the `req.file` object.

My question now: how can I get multer to work with multer-s3's file definition rather than its own? Prior to migrating to typescript, all of the properties contained in multer-s3's type definitions for "File" were accessible under `req.file` - unfortunately, typescript doesn't recognize that. So far I'm somehow using a workaround by creating a new property on my request interface of type `Express.MulterS3.File`:

```
export default interface IRequest extends express.Request {
  processedFile?: Express.MulterS3.File;
}
```

And then, inside the parsing middleware, cast down the `req.file` property to `Express.MulterS3.File`, which makes the needed properties available:

```
export const acceptProfilePicUpload = async function (
  req: IRequest,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      multerUpload(req, res, (err: any) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(true);
      });
    });

    if (!req.file)
      throw new Error("file missing");

    req.processedFile = req.file as Express.MulterS3.File; // this is how I get TS to user multer-s3's type definitions - is there a better solution?    

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
};
```

However, I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it and would kindly like to ask for your help on this issue. My goal is to simply have `req.file` be of type `Express.MulterS3.File` rather than `Express.Multer.File`.

Maybe some of you know where the issue lies or encountered it themselves when working with multer-s3 & multer in typescript. **Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue merging the types `Express.Multer.File` and `Express.MulterS3.File`.

First, you have to overwrite the type `Express.Request.file` from `express`. You can do that by using the key `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`. The key receives an array of strings, each string has to be a path that specifies a folder which acts like `./node_modules/@types`. Using this key, you'll be able to overwrite types from `express` or any other library.

Here is my `typeRoots`:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/@types"
],
```

Then, create a file with your `Express.Request.file` declaration, for example, here is my `express.d.ts` (the file could have any name):

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    file: Express.Multer.File & Express.MulterS3.File;
  }
}
```

If you want to change the type of `req.file` only for `Express.MulterS3.File` rather than both, you can write:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    file: Express.MulterS3.File;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if we can put that inside https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/multer-s3/index.d.ts ? I'm no typescript expert, would this be reasonable ?